# Does it matter what webserver (Apache, IIS, ...) is used with Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, apache, iis

I want to develop a geoportal using GeoServer. I installed GeoServer and Apache and I think the connection between the two of them is done.

Today my boss told me about IIS. what i want to know is if i develop geoportal with Apache it will work also in ISS ? what should i modify if i copy the project in ISS ? what are the configurations that i have to do in this case ?

Comment: Without doing some initial research on your own and then sharing the result of that research, as well as detailing what *specific* concerns you have regarding GeoServer, I am going to say this question is off topic because it is basically an "Apache vs. IIS" question which has no business here. Try [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) instead (but expect to be chided if you do not research before asking a question there, they tend to be even less forgiving).

Comment: ok sorry !! but i just try to have an idea about "Apache vs IIS" and what is the best for geoserver not in general that's why i ask the question here and not in StackOverflow..Anyway i'm sorry again.

Comment: in that case it would be better phrased along the lines of *"Does it matter what webserver (Apache, IIS, ...) is used with Geoserver?"* followed by a rough description of what the business goals are (best interactive maps of ski hills in Yagamarphoo), what environment is like (all windows/linux/mac machines, primarily using ___ GIS software) and what kind of background or skillsets you and your colleagues are bringing to bear.

Comment: i'm not too good in english that why i found some difficulties to phrase my questions !! i will edit my question now and clarify my problem..thank you guys

Comment: In regards to your latest edit, you have not really done anything to narrow down the scope of the question, only asked more questions, which is not in the spirit of the "1 question, 1 answer" philosophy of this site. At this point the only useful information is that you're using GeoServer. But that's still not nearly enough to go on.

Comment: If the language barrier is a problem you might try posting in both English and your native language and hopefully someone will help translate. The important thing though is that you demonstrate that you've researched the topic to a reasonable degree, and add details to make the question more specific and focused. See the Help Center topic on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as the meta question [How to frame a good Question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3349/753) for more suggestions.

Comment: Ok, i will do some research about that before asking here. Should i now delete this question or not ?

Comment: Up to you. I would suggest that you just edit your question when you are ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference between IIS and Apache is the price - Apache is free. If you don't need .NET integration and you're new to web servers, Apache is probably your best bet.

Comment: if i develop my geoportail using apache as u said, and when i will finish my work and i give it to my boss, it will be a problem if he use a iis or it doesn't matter ? because he told me that he will install the iis for this geoportail !! what do you think ?

Comment: If you're referencing ESRI Geoportal, it was developed under the Apache license. It will function with IIS as well, but you'll then have to configure both. Ideally you would only configure everything once, but you could develop on Apache and move to IIS, it will just mean some extra work later on.

Comment: sorry but some extra work like what ? i mean easy work or not ? just to explain to my boss the whole situation !!

Comment: Easiest way to explain something like this to boss goes something like this: if Apache we can use linux server and save lots of money is we ever need to get more servers , if IIS it's at least xxx€ to licenses for every server and lots of headache from licensing. From my experience it is easier to develop with LAMP stack than IIS because there is more people talking and using free software